# SFTP works over linux command line but filezilla fails

Tags: sftp

I have set up an ftp user on my ubuntu server.  I can sftp in to ftp_user@ip, am asked for my password, and get connected fine.

Filezilla (which worked 3 months ago), doesn't connect.  This is a redacted version of the ssh logs:

```
Jul 19 14:18:33 sshd[14275]: Invalid user user from  port 47990
Jul 19 14:18:33 sshd[14275]: Received disconnect from  port 47990:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 19 14:18:33 sshd[14275]: Disconnected from invalid user user  port 47990 [preauth]
Jul 19 14:18:44 sshd[14277]: Invalid user user from  port 48558
Jul 19 14:18:44 sshd[14277]: Received disconnect from  port 48558:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 19 14:18:44 sshd[14277]: Disconnected from invalid user user  port 48558 [preauth]
Jul 19 14:18:55 sshd[14282]: Invalid user user from port 49142
Jul 19 14:18:55 sshd[14282]: Received disconnect from  port 49142:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 19 14:18:55 sshd[14282]: Disconnected from invalid user user port 49142 [preauth]
```

This sounds like Filezilla is trying user "user", which is not correct, but my settings has:

[image]

EDIT: it works if I use the quickconnect bar, but not the above main settings.

What am I doing wrong?